# Getting 401.1 web response while testing Silverlight Application with fiddler

Tags: silverlight, iis, ria, fiddler, ntlm

I need to stress-test a silverlight application which uses Windows authentication mode. To achieve this task I am using the StressStimulus Fiddler addin.

What I am doing is to log in and doing some stuff like search etc. I captured the HTTP messages transferred  in Fiddler and replayed them using the above mentioned tool.

However, when I replay the packages I always get a 401.1 Server responses.

I tried to use different Authorization approaches (NTLM and Negotiate) but I always get the same response message.

Fiddler seems to be properly configured. In the Fiddler options menun "Reuse client connection" is checked as well as "Reuse connection to server". I even raised the KeepAliveTimeout in the registry without any success.

Does anybody have an idea whats going wrong?

Comment: Generally speaking, you can configure Fiddler to automatically handle HTTP/401 challenges for you using your current Windows credentials. You can set the X-AutoAuth flag; see comments at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2010/08/12/using-reflection-to-get-ntlm-negotiate-challenge-response-string-without-sending-request-using-webrequest-object.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't replay authentications such as NTLM and Negotiate.  One the most important features of any challange/response authentication is that it must not be replayable.  Without this feature an attacker can monitor a successful authentication and then replay the same sequence to gain access to things they aren't entitled.